# Add row to Datagridview with no columns

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview

Is there a way to append 1 or 2 rows to the bottom of my Datagridview with no columns? My current DataGridView has 3 columns, but I want 1 or 2 rows at the bottom to "summarize" the above content. I've tried `dataGridView1.Rows.Add("Test");` but that just adds "Test" to my first column in a new row. Is this possible?

Thanks!

Comment: Datagridview has no build-in support for col- or rowspan. But here is a link that shows you how you can achieve it with some coding: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/bca20055-635b-4da0-a6c4-a4527ba22e9d/datagridview-rowspan

Comment: You could try the clone method. Then don't input any data.    Example:

                        DataGridViewRow row = (DataGridViewRow)dataGridView1.Rows[0].Clone();
                        dataGridView1.Rows.Add(row);

Comment: Have you tried using labels in the footer of your gridview? That is what I usually do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest solution would be to create a second DataGridView directly below the first. Then manually populate it with the single row that you want to be displayed with summary and to make it look like a single gridview, just make column header invisible for the second grid view using the following line

```
dataGridViewSummary.ColumnHeadersVisible = false;
```